# SQL join using EF Core

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am a bit stuck and would appreciate some help.
I have the following data structure as shown in the image below.

[image]

So I want to link C and D basically apply the list to list. And if possible how would I do this in ef core. I did try a different query

```
SELECT * FROM A a 
JOIN B b on a.PKA= B.PKB
```

But I only get the multiplication of list every record from table B got a pair for every record of table A. One more question if records in table C don't have the same number of record in table D it values should be null

Comment: Sorry  i use SQL serve i did remove tag sorry for that

Comment: Please clarify "link C and D basically apply the list to list". With proper navigation properties it's easy to get two lists `a.Cs` and `a.B.Ds`, but how you correlate C record to D record?

Comment: Yes, it is easy to get 2 lists but how to join them for example for this query
`select distinct * from C c join D d on c.PKB =d.PKA` since it is 1-1 relation but when I try to do this with EF i get multiplication and i put Distinct() at end and i know that EF is using Equals below that

Comment: This is what I meant by "needs clarification". Parent PK is not enough (it's does not uniquely identify child records), you need to map (join) the C and D records by some secondary key.